# JavaFX stops working when module-info.java file created in VSCode

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code, java-17

When I add the module-info.java file to the src folder in my java project I get errors:
[Image of the errors and my folder setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C92Xi.jpg)

When I remove the module-info.java file the errors go, but I need the module-info file

module-info.java:

```
module JavaFXtest{

}
```

haven't started adding things, however whenever I add a requirement, it says e.g.: javafx.fxml cannot be resolved to a module
(all the javafx jar files are in the referenced libraries)

Comment: Include your `module-info.java` code.

Comment: @James_D this is the code, its just a empty module: module JavaFXtest{
    
}

Comment: @James_D I have added it to the questions, thanks

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, it needs to state which other modules you require.

Comment: @James_D hi, I wrote requires javafx.fxml to test this, but it says javafx.fxml cannot to be resolved to a module

Comment: work through a tutorial about how to setup a modular java project (there are example projects that are _guaranteed_ to work), modify until you feel confident with modules. Repeat with javafx :)

Comment: hi @kleopatra I did that, but they didn't include them making a module-info.java file. I followed everything else.

Comment: it seems to be working without the module-info.java file

Comment: vscode adds this when I run the file
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @/var/folders/b2/vthc46790gsgmg2qcm_50y1m0000gn/T/cp_bmjv1o5iwefrl2apgdd3tv0yb.argfile test.Main

Comment: _they didn't include them making a module-info.java file_ then find a tutorial that explains how to configure VS with java modules, pretty sure there's more than one ;) Basically, that's unrelated to fx - you _have to_ understand the java module system before going on, there is no way around.

Comment: @kleopatra I watched every single one on YouTube, please check to the answer I submitted for this post

Comment: _I watched every single one on YouTube_ you know that can't be true, given the myriads of videos :) Glad you found a solution, though.

Comment: @kleopatra I did.

Answer (score 2):

Your `module-info.java` should specify which other modules you require,  and if necessary should export packages from your module. See, e.g. https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html for a description.

```
module JavaFXtest{
    requires javafx.controls ;
    requires javafx.fxml ;
    exports com.example.mypackage ;
}
```

where the last line specifies the package with your `Application` subclass.

You also need to ensure that the JavaFX modules are on the module path. The preferred approach is to use a dependency management tool,  such as Maven or Gradle, to manage all this for you. See the "Getting Started" instructions at [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: Hi, I added this: module JavaFXtest{
    requires javafx.controls ;
    requires javafx.fxml ;
    exports sample;
} I still get the error that states java.fx.fxml cannot be resolved to a module

Comment: @ninesw See edit. If you're seeing that error you presumably don't have the `javafx.fxml` module (which is a separate module to `javafx.controls`).

Comment: I thought all the modules would be automatically in my project when I add the javafx jar files to referenced libraries.

Comment: @ninesw I don't know VSCode, so don't know how it configures execution, but they need to be on the module path (not just the classpath).

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I edited the launch.json file and added this:

"vmArgs": "--module-path \ "/Users/(name)/Documents/lib/javafx-sdk-    17.0.0.1/lib\ "  --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

where name is the users name.
The directory leads to the directory of the library folder of the javafx-sdk.

the path must be in `""`, so I added `\` before the `"` so this works and so it doesn't escape the outer `" "`.

What this does is when you run your application, vscode adds the arguments to add the required modules from the referenced libraries at runtime. Therefore you do not need a module-info.java file to run.